# How can I verify that my flag was recorded?

Tags: support, flags

I read a comment I found problematic.  I clicked on the little flag, chose the bottom-most radio button in the list of reasons for flagging, and wrote a short text in the input box.  I submitted the flag but no acknowledgment message appeared.  Should one have appeared?

Is there any way for me to verify that my flag actually went out?

Is there any way for me to find out later what the outcome of the flag was?

Is there any way for me to read what I wrote?

What about flags on my own posts?  Is there any info about these that I can see?

I have tried looking at the various similar questions that were suggested by the software, but none of them are recent, and I suspect that the answers that I found through this approach are obsolete.

Comment: I tried re-flagging, to be on the safe side, and a helpful message appeared, saying that I had already flagged that comment.  I suppose that's better than nothing!

Comment: If the flag was not recorded, you will get an error message saying so.

Comment: I just attempted to flag this question and go offline to bring up the error message that appears if your flag fails. Goddammit, I actually flagged it successfully by accident. Sorry to the mod that is reviewing my flag right now.

Comment: I find the word "problematic" to be problematic.

Comment: @Won't - If it's the word you've got a problem with, how about proposing an alternative?

Comment: Why not say what you mean? A stupid comment?  A trolling comment?  Was the comment obsolete?  Incorrect?  Foolish?  Was it obtuse?  Or maybe it was offensive?  Or perhaps it was just shitty?  Why obfuscate?

Comment: @Won't - Cool it, friend, this isn't worth getting so worked up about.  ---  Why didn't I say something more specific than *problematic*?  Because my specific reaction to that particular post is irrelevant to my getting more adept with the software.

Comment: Cool what?  You asked a question, and I answered it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you look on your **Activity** tab in your profile, go across to the right hand side in a box labelled **Impact**, there is a button that says '**x helpful flags** (where x indicates a number)

[image]

click on that and all the details of your flags (and the moderator responses) are listed.